# Returns two results with database in one object MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I tried do query which will return me 2 results, in

- first will be all boards where match board.users == user._id and
- second result where will be all boards where board._id is equall some with array.

  ```
  db.getCollection('boards').aggregate( 
  [ 
    {
   $group: 

          {
                _id: { users : ObjectId("59cd114cea98d9326ca1c421") },
                name: { $push:  { name: "$name", _id: "$_id" }    }
          } 
   },
      {
   $group:  
          {
                _id: { _id :  { $in: [ObjectId("59cd1f9a71b8ad5f48eb74f6"), ObjectId("59ecf24ca3a60c06d06e5088")] } },
                favorite: { $push:  { name: "$name", _id: "$_id" } },
          } 
   }
    ]
  )
  ```

I know this is badly written, could someone direct me and write about this comment to improve? Please.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by doing a `find` instead of `aggregate`. Something like this:

```
db.getCollection('boards').find({$or:[CONDITION_1 , CONDITION_2]});
```

CONDITION_1 seems to be an [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch)

CONDITION_2 seems to be a [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in)

Comment: Hey thanks for answer, I have question, If I will make find it will return me 1 result where I want have two results in first variable of object I want have all boards and in second I want have all boards only which are save to favorite. U understand ? :P i think this way is not good??